# How to use spacy to count the number of words in each row of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spacy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A', '</b>          A 1960\'s era\n\n<b>'], ['B', '</b>           Yeah, I know.\n'], ['C', '</b>           This is a cute cat\n\n<b>']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'text'])
>>> df
  id                                      text
0  A         </b>          A 1960's era\n\n<b>
1  B            </b>           Yeah, I know.\n
2  C  </b>           This is a cute cat\n\n<b>
```

Any suggestions to use spacy to count the number of words?

The ideal output is:

```
data = [['A', '</b>          A 1960\'s era\n\n<b>', 3], ['B', '</b>           Yeah, I know.\n' , 3], ['C', '</b>           This is a cute cat\n\n<b>',5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'text','number_of_words'])
>>> df
  id                                      text  number_of_words
0  A         </b>          A 1960's era\n\n<b>                3
1  B            </b>           Yeah, I know.\n                3
2  C  </b>           This is a cute cat\n\n<b>                5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not spacy, but maybe...

**Try:**

```
df['text2'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'<[^>]*>', '', regex=True).str.strip()
df['len'] = df['text2'].str.split().str.len()
print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
    id  text                            text2               len
0   A   </b> A 1960's era\n\n<b>        A 1960's era        3
1   B   </b> Yeah, I know.\n            Yeah, I know.       3
2   C   </b> This is a cute cat\n\n<b>  This is a cute cat  5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the spacy tokenizer, I would suggest some list comprehension:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
myvals = df['text'].values.tolist()

df['number_of_words'] = [len([i for i in nlp(re.sub('</b>|<b>', '', i2)) if not (i.is_space or i.is_punct)]) for i2 in myvals]
```

The one-liner says basically: for element in list, get rid of html markers, process with spacy and count the tokens if it is neither space nor punctuation.

Output:

```
id  text                               number_of_words
0   A   </b> A 1960's era\n\n<b>       4
1   B   </b> Yeah, I know.\n           3
2   C   </b> This is a cute cat\n\n<b> 5
```

But as you see, '1960's' was here counted as two tokens by spacy.

So, unless there is a huge advantage for you to use spacy or you do need a specific tokenizer, counting words by simply splitting spaces would be definitly the preferred way, just as suggested by
[@MDR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9192284/mdr)